# Returning char* to print in C

Tags: arrays, c, string, linked-list, char

So I am trying to print out a `char *` array after being returned from a function but I keep getting a segmentation fault.

```
char *return(node *n) {
    node *p = list->head;
    int count = 0;
    int size = 0;

    while (p != NULL) {
        size += strlen(p->name);
        count++;
        p = p->nxt;
    }

    size = size + 1; // for the '\0'

    char *arr[count][size];
    p = list->head;
    count = 0;

    while (p != NULL) {
        strcpy(arr[count], p->name);
        count++;
        p = p->next;
   }
   return arr;
}
```

I then go to try and print it out in my `main` function on a certain node. and I get a segmentation fault.

```
char *test = return(node1);
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
     printf("%s", test[i]);
}
```

Comment: The type of test[i] is __char__, so your print statement should be __printf("%c", test[i]);__.  But there are other bigger problems with your code.

Comment: How can you have a function named return ? "return" is a keyword in C.
This program should not even compile.

Answer (score 3):

Your `arr` is local to the (unfortunately named) function. When the function exits, the space is deallocated. If you use that pointer afterwards, you are indexing into unknown, and most likely somewhere you're not supposed to (which results in a segfault).

When you want to allocate space in a function and return a pointer, you should use `malloc` (or equivalent), and remember to `free` the space afterwards. An alternate way is to have the pointer be a parameter to the function, and leave the reponsibility for allocation (and deallocation) to the caller (like `fgets` does).

Approach 1 (allocation inside the function):

```
char *foo() {
  char *arr = malloc(100);
  return arr;
}

/* somewhere else */
char *arr = foo();
/* use arr */
free(arr);
```

Approach 2 (allocation outside the function):

```
void foo(char *arr, size_t size) {
  /* do stuff to arr */
}

/* somewhere else */
char *arr = char[100];
foo(arr, 100);
```

EDIT: Was wrong. Ignore what was here.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Your approach 1 is how I tried printing it. But it still seg faults. Theres no way to return a char* array and then print it out again somewhere else?

Comment: Not with `char *arr[count][size]` (which is what I see in your code). You can by manually allocating it with `malloc` (it gets a bit complicated since it's two-dimensional). Actually, if you're not changing the strings, you can just allocate an array of `char**`, and copy the pointer (without `strcpy`ing the string), using `arr = calloc(count, sizeof(char*))` and later `arr[count] = p->name`. If the strings need to be duplicated, you would need one allocation for the array of pointers as above, and another allocation inside the loop, to allocate space for each string's copy.

Comment: Not sure If I udnerstand the char**. I create it and calloc(count, sizeofchar*)). in my while loop instead of strcpy i just do arr[count] = p->name. How would I then print that char** if i return it?

Comment: Exactly as you are. (By the way, `char *arr[count][size]` was probably a misspelling of `char arr[count][size]`, if you have `count` strings of `size` characters?) `printf("%s", arr[0])` should print the first element as string.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I still can't seem to get it. I will keep playing around with it, I appreciate it